# Modulo de STRING y INT

Tags: c++, string

Tengo un problema a la hora de resolver un problema,el cual me pide que a un string N le saque el modulo de un entero D (los valores de estos,son grandes),el problema,es que cuando utilizo la funcion "stoi" me salta un error,Como lo puedo solucionar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aca esta el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int aprendiendo(string n,int d){
    int resultado;
    int comb = stoi(n);
    resultado = comb % d;
    return resultado;
}
int main() {
    string n; int d;
    cin>>n>>d;
    cout<<aprendiendo(n,d)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira el error. Te dice fuera de rango... La pregunta es: cuál es el valor máximo de un entero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si consultamos la documentación del error que recibes (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range).
>
> Define un tipo de objeto que será lanzado como excepción. **Infoma de errores que son consecuencia de intentar acceder elementos fuera de un rango definido**. Puede ser lanzado por funciones miembo de `std::bitset` y `std::basic_string`, **por `std::stoi`** y las familias de funciones `std::stod`, y por funciones que comprueban rangos (como `std::vector::at` y `std::map::at`).

Vemos que es un error que puede ser lanzado por `std::stoi`, consultemos su documentación (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### `std::stoi`
>
> **Excepciones**
>
> - `std::invalid_argument` si la conversión no se puede llevar a cabo.
> - **`std::out_of_range` si el valor convertido no cabe en el tipo resultante** o si la función subyacente (`std::strtol` `std::stroll`) establece `errno` a `ERANGE`.

La función `std::stoi` convierte a entero (`int`), un entero de 32 bits puede almacenar 2<sup>32</sup> valores (4.294.967.296) repartidos entre positivos y negativos. El valor que has intentado convertir a entero (123.123.232.323.244.549.849) es mayor a 2<sup>32</sup> (y mayor a 2<sup>64</sup>) por lo tanto no cabe en un entero de 32 bits, de ahí el error.